# Set click event dynamically at runtime but not just after jQuery loading finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, click

My issue is that I want to **set** a **click event dynamically**. So imagine I have a button. Clicking that button shows a popup box.

In that box I have a text like this:

```
"Men in <span class='timelineplace-bulgaria'>Bulgaria</span>"
```

But the issue is that I don't have access to the button event. So I would like to set the click event with an **regex** like this:

```
$("[class*='timelineplace']").click(function () {
    var object = $(this);
    alert(object.attr("class").match(/timelineplace-(.*?)(?:\s+|$)/)[1]);
});
```

But yeah this only works when the popup box already existed when jQuery loading finished. So the issue is that the popup is dynamically loaded. And the click event is set when the site has finished the loadings.

So Is there a way to set a click event also at runtime to any regex matching class? Or do I really have to go to the button click event and set the onclick there.

Comment: Always the same question :)

Comment: Already tried that but did not work. Now again tested and still not working. =(

Comment: `$("[class*='timelineplace']").on("click","select", function() {
    var object = $(this);
    alert(object.attr("class").match(/timelineplace-(.*?)(?:\s+|$)/)[1]);
});` btw

Comment: Replace `[class*='timelineplace']` with `[class*=timelineplace]`

Comment: Still now alert =/, also tested `$("[class*=timelineplace]").live("click", function() {
    var object = $(this);
    alert(object.attr("class").match(/timelineplace-(.*?)(?:\s+|$)/)[1]);
});`

Comment: It seems that the regex has issue when used without `.click`

Comment: `$("#somebutton").on("click", function() {
    alert(56456);
});` working but `$("[class*=timelineplace]").on("click", function() {
    alert(56456);
});` does not and I have this one somewhere else that is also working `$("[class*='event']").click(function () {
    alert(56456);
}`

Comment: Well actually it is not a regex issue. It is just the same issue I had from the very start. Because even `$(".timelineplace-plaza").on("click",function() {
    alert(8);
});` is not working. So even without regex it does not set the onclick event correctly.

Comment: It's working for me : http://jsfiddle.net/vve1dLyx/ I get an alert with "Bulgaria"

Comment: Yeah if the html and classes already exists. It works for sure. But I load that string with the class dynamically. And then I'm not able to set the onclick event =/

Comment: Here you go. http://jsfiddle.net/kwoxer/vve1dLyx/2/ This is the issue I have. When the class is changed or just created at runtime. Then it does not match anymore. But it must be possible to do that somehow. There need to be a solution for that. =/ Btw it not the concrete issue. I just added that class to show the issue to you =) And could you please remove the duplicate from the title. Thank you.

Comment: So THAT's the question everyone asks. I have updated my fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/vve1dLyx/3/

Comment: Ahh working :D Okay so putting it on the document and not the class. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yeah this syntax works for present and future elements.